# Return link not supported by Internet Explorer 7 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-7

I am using jQuery and Ajax, and my `Ajax.php` file returns the following field into the main file. While I am clicking in Mozilla and Chrome, it is working fine and gives an alert, but when I use Internet Explorer 7 (version 7.0.5730.13), it wasn't supported. Do I need to do anything on browser side or do I have to modify it?

Here is what my `Ajax.php` file has:

```
echo " <a href='#' onclick=\"javascript:alert('hello')\ "> link</a>";
```

It returns to the main .html file. There I didn't get an alert in Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to get rid of the extra space after the closing parenthesis (this may just be a typo in your post, though), put in a semi-colon, and return false so that it doesn't attempt to follow the link.

```
echo " <a href='#' onclick=\"javascript:alert('hello'); return false;\"> link</a>";
```

Comment: I have done the above code , I am surprise how its working in mozilla and chrome and not work iE7 may i know its reason?

Comment: Just guessing, but I can think of a couple of ways this might happen.  Moz/Chrome may not flush the event queue when the link is to the same page and thus the alert event happens despite the link being followed or Moz/Chrome may handle the alert before following the link whereas IE doesn't.

Comment: Adding return false causes the link processing to be aborted so that following the link doesn't flush the pending javascript operations.

Comment: Thanks However I still in the process of searching and modifying the code

Answer (score 1):

It could be the space between the `/` and the `"`.

Comment: Is there any Equivalent syntax for ? echo " <a href='#' onclick=\"javascript:alert('hello'); return false;\"> link</a>";

Answer (score 1):

You also don't need label "javascript" in your onClick event.

You can read more about it in [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Proper way of calling a JavaScript method*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761167/proper-way-of-calling-a-javascript-method/3761175#3761175).